# So what does "return 0" actually mean?

Tags: c, return

I'm pretty proficient in PHP, but I've started dabbling with C. I've seen the code

```
return 0;
```

at the end of functions that don't return a value. This isn't used in PHP, because if a function is doesn't have a return, a value NULL is automatically returned.

All I'm asking is, in simple English, what does the `return 0` actually do? Is it like PHP, where it returns its argument as the value of the function call? Is it just good practice?

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I'm asking it from the point of view of a PHP developer. The answers google throws up haven't been that concise.

Comment: `at the end of functions that don't return a value` You mean `void` functions?

Comment: Don't know about C but some languages need a :void (as :Number or :String) in functions that don't return values.

Comment: @Cicade Sorry - yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: post the function signature. Does it look like one of the following three? int foo(void); void foo(void); foo(void);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is it like php, where it returns its argument as the value of the
>   function call? Is it just good practise?

Yes, PHP and many other languages borrowed the `return` keyword from 'C'. And in all the languages, the `return` keyword has the same function - to return from the function. Anything that follows `return` keyword is the value that is returned to the caller.

Is it a good practise? Yes and No. Not all functions **should** return a value. And quite a few in the standard library even, do not return any value. Hence their return type is `void`.

But `main` function should return `0`(also `EXIT_SUCCESS`) to identify that the program has executed successfully. And -1 otherwise (also `EXIT_FAILURE`)

EDIT: (Thanks to @KeithThompson):

`EXIT_FAILURE` is implementation defined. `1` is a common value of `EXIT_FAILURE` but the whole point is, you need not know.

Comment: Ah, I see. Great answer. I know it's a simple question, but I just like to clarify everything 100% in my head before throwing myself at projects!

Comment: @JWH that's great. I support clarity of thought while programming

Comment: The value of `EXIT_FAILURE` is implementation-defined. It's *not* typically `-1`; `1` is more common. But the whole point is that you don't have to know `our care what the value is.

Comment: @KeithThompson agreed

Comment: Actually, `main()` is the one *non-void* function that does *not* need a `return 0;`. For `main()`, and only for `main()`, the `return 0;` is implicit.

Comment: Disagree with "And -1 otherwise".  `main()` returns all sorts of `int` values and the value is program dependent.

Answer (score 9):

For historic reasons, it is possible to write `return 0;` to return from a function that has been declared as `void`, like so:

```
void foo( /* arguments */ )
{
  /* do things */
  return 0;
}
```

This does nothing, and the `0` (or whatever you put there) is thrown away.  Also, sensible compilers will give you a warning message if you do this.  So don't do this.

Comment: This is a constraint violation in Standard C.  (So it's only "possible" in the sense that anything is possible)

Answer (score 7):

Functions in C return int by default, if no other return type is defined. return 0 would be good practice to make sure the function returns a known value, as opposed to some random value, in case the caller is looking at the return value.

Comment: Worth noting that this is ANSI C, and modern C (C99 and newer) discourage or disallow inferred types.

Comment: this is the case with c89 only

Comment: Is it really good practice to encourage people to inspect the return value of a function that has been declared as not returning a value?

Comment: The meaning of *"Functions in C return int by default,"* is that in K&R and c90 it was OK with the compiler to write `foo(){return 1;}` for a function taking an arbitrary number of arguments of unspecified type and returning `int`. No, it is not good practice to rely on that behavior in writing new code, but the compiler needs to support it because there is legacy code out there.

Answer (score 6):

It is literally returning an int of 0.

Answer (score 3):

The C programming language allows programs exiting or returning from the main function to signal success or failure by returning an integer, or returning the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. On Unix these are equal to 0 and 1 respectively. A C program may also use the `exit()` function specifying the integer status or exit macro as the first parameter.

Apart from the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, the C standard does not define the meaning of return codes. Rules for the use of return codes vary on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

In C you don't have to return a value only if you declare a function with void at the start of it.
First example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
{
   printf("Hello World!");
    return 0; // you have to use return because main starting with int
}
```

Second Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello World!");
//in this case return is useless, main is a void function

}
```

Comment: IN first example what it is returning ?

Answer (score 1):

`return 0` literally returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`. Even if you do not type in `return 0` it will automatically `return 0` for you. Check out [this](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) (Search for *The return value of main*) link for more information.

---

A quick snapshot from that link:

[image]