# Use of return in a program

Tags: c, mingw

While writing a block of code in int main() block,why do we use

return 0;

I know it's because it tells the OS that the code ran successfully.
But even if I use things like return 1, return 38 or similar things how does it effect me if my program still runs successfully.
What's the use of the numeric 0 then if any number number x can do the same?

Comment: The return value can be used by the OS (not the compiler) to report the exit code of your program, or take further action.

Comment: Because 0 means a [successful exit.](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)

Comment: @Weather: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Eren But my program runs successfully even with return 15; .How does return 0 change the thing for it?

Comment: @AnujSingh It's just a convention. You can return 15 but it would be confusing to someone reading your code. It may actually a cause a problem too, depending on the environment you're running it.

Comment: @Eric Can a main() function's value be used in other programs I make? By value I mean the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any value different from zero is a sign that program ended abnormally or with an error. For stand-alone programs it doesn't really matter all that much, as this code is often ignored. However, for when called within a third party software, the OS, a script, or a shell, this could be used for error handling.

Reference to a similar question. [So what does "return 0" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928520/so-what-does-return-0-actually-mean)

Also a reference to a Quora Question:
https://www.quora.com/What-does-return-1-do-in-a-program-in-C

Answer (score 2):

In many environments, the return value passed back from `main()` can be accessed by whatever ran your program. For example, you can see this in `bash` by doing something like (`$?` is the `bash` special variable holding the return code from the last program - it's actually a bit more complex than that when you do pipelines but we'll keep it simple for the purposes of this question):

```
myProgram
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Something went horribly wrong"
fi
```

So it's a good way to indicate success or otherwise of your program to "the outside world".

For the language lawyer amongst us, it's covered (for `C11`) first in `5.1.2.2.3 Program termination /1` (my emphasis):

> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, ***a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument;*** reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

Section `7.22.4.4 The exit function /5` covers the behaviour of `exit` as it pertains to actually finishing execution:

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.